# Show earliest wordpress post of current category

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a link to a first post of the current category in "single" template, outside of the post query.

Found this piece of code which originally would list all posts in the current category, which I figured would later be cropped.

It works fine but I can't list posts in ascending order.

```
$category = get_the_category();
foreach ($category as $cat)
{
    query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, '&order=ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) );
    echo '<div class="post">';
    echo '<h2>'.$cat->cat_name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';
    while (have_posts())
    {
        the_post();
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    $category_id = get_cat_ID($cat->cat_name);
    $category_link = get_category_link($category_id);
    echo '<div class="paging">';
    echo '<a href="'.$category_link.'" title="'.$cat->cat_name.'">More Post from '.$cat->cat_name.'</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this example from the docs for [`query_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts):

```
query_posts( array( 'category__and' => array(1,3), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Try changing your `query_posts()` call to this:

```
query_posts( array ( 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID, 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => 1  ) );
```

You may also have to add the `orderby` attribute.